# pyqt code is blocking although moved to a different QThread

Tags: pyqt, qthread, qtimer

I tried to make my PyQt4 program more responsive by moving some blocking code to a seperate QThread. As it didn't work, I created this minimal example as a demonstration:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Sleeper(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Sleeper, self).__init__()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.sleep)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def sleep(self):
        time.sleep(1)


class MyGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("hello", self)
        self.sleeper = Sleeper()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.sleeper.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_gui = MyGUI()
    my_gui.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

The problem with this code is that the sleep-command still blocks the user interface. I found that it works as expected when I create, connect and run the QTimer outside the Sleeper class, but I do not understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `connect` is called while the object was in the GUI thread so the event handler will also be executed in the GUI thread. Try moving to thread first, then creating the connection.

```
class Sleeper(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Sleeper, self).__init__()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()

    def initialize(self): # Creating the connection and starting separately
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.sleep)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def sleep(self):
        time.sleep(1)

class MyGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("hello", self)
        self.sleeper = Sleeper()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.sleeper.moveToThread(self.thread) # Move to thread
        self.sleeper.initialize() # Create connection now
        self.thread.start()
```

Also, check this:
[Qt connection type between threads: why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101379/qt-connection-type-between-threads-why-does-this-work)